# Fallback location for psr-0/4 autoloading

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

I'm building a PHP package and in it I have a folder (let's say `/vendor/myvendor/packagename/src/Classes`) which I want to autoload using PSR-4.

But I would also like to provide an option to copy that folder from its current location to the project root (let's say `/packagename/Classes`, something along the lines of Laravel's `publish` command).

So how could I go about autoloading it?

I would like Composer to first see if the folder exists under the app's root, and if it does then autoload that. Else fall back to the default location inside `/vendor`. Is that possible?

FWIW, this is Laravel specific package, which means that I could use Laravel's `publish` command to copy the entire folder where ever, but then

1. I would have to manually add the new location to autoload;
2. Even if I do, there would be namespace conflict between the old and new location.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like Composer to first see if the folder exists under the app's root, and if it does then autoload that. Else fall back to the default location inside /vendor. Is that possible?

**Yes, it is possible.**

You need to mention everything on your `ServiceProvider` for your package.

There are every informations about how to publish your views, assets in the docs and it fits your needs.

Have a look at the docs:

> https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/packages#public-assets

I am copying some example for you over here:

If you want to publish your translations, you need to perform this task:

```
/**
 * Perform post-registration booting of services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/translations', 'courier');

    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/path/to/translations' => resource_path('lang/vendor/courier'),
    ]);
}
```

If you don't have translation in `app's` `lang/vendor/courier` then it falls back to your package translation.

**You don't need to copy your class codes, which could remain in your package directory. The only things you copy will be your views, assets, translation files etc.**

This should help you.

Comment: PaladiN that far I got. I know I can publish my package's config and assets without a problem. But my question isn't about publishing assets or config, but PHP classes. How can I achieve the same result with PHP classes? How can I copy a PSR-4 structured folder outside of my package AND autoload it AND resolve namespace conflict?

Comment: I cannot find any scenario that you need to copy the classes from your package. If that is the case i suggest you not to use packages and work from your `app` directory. I am unknown about your scenario but as i understand that shouldnot be done for most case. If you could mention your scenario i could think about it.

Comment: Yes, I was just about to comment on that. I'm not too sure myself if this is a good idea, so that's why I asked if it was advisable or not. My idea is to give the end user the ability to modify my code without messing with the `vendor` directory. John Doe installs my package, exports the PSR-4 folder outside of `/vendor`, and they can tinker with it all they want. Are there any down sides to this approach?

Comment: if that is the case i might not have much knowledge about that and let's wait for other suggestion, but from the knowledge i have there is no any issue with that except the namespace (as you told in the question).  The person who is working on the code in `app` should only change the namespace if removed or added. There might be no any other downside than this.

Comment: For a reference, I'm guessing my approach may present needless complexity with potential issues with updates and backward compatibility., as well as a need for documentation because it's non-standard An alternative is to give up exporting PHP code and just have my package in a public repo on GitHub, so that anyone can clone and modify it **before** they install it.

Comment: I suppose it is a bad practise to do. Alternatively you could create a standard package which doesn't need to be modified by the user and the user could extend your package and add more functionality if needed.